# Expo Build completed but it is not finishing so that I can download it

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo build that I am running in order to submit it to the app store. It says that it is still building but when i go into the logs it shows that it is complete. I do not know why it got stuck on this step and how to fix it. What should I do.

[image: expo build]

it usually shows that i can download the build in order to submit it to app store but it just shows queued even though it completed the build.

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary issue with the website a couple hours ago. Specifically build job statuses weren't being synced with the website, causing completed builds to remain in a "Queued" state. This issue has been resolved and builds now show their correct statuses. Successfully completed builds will now show a "Finished" state and be downloadable.